Is there a way for Windows to behave like a Mac when drag a file into a upload window?
When uploading an item like attaching a file on email on Windows, when I drag the file into the popup window, Windows will move the file to that current directory of the window, where Mac will instead - showing the directory the file is currently on. Is there a way for Windows to behave like Mac, so I can drag the file to upload instead of moving the file to that directory?
EDIT:
To clarify, I am referring to either a web email client or any other web UI that requires you to upload a file. Like Mac, on windows, a window pops out and ask you select an item to upload. But if the item is not in the directory of the window popped out, I want to drag the file into the window popout. In Mac, the popout window will change to show the directory the file is in, but in Window, it will move the item I dragged to that directory instead

Your question is unclear. Which email client? What other "upload" situation are you speaking of? Attaching something to an email does not move the file, though I support SOME email clients may move a file to a temporary folder as part of their process, but attaching a file to email isn't typically referred to as "uploading" the file. Please think carefully about the problem you are facing and how best to describe it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In general you cannot modify Windows to act like macOS.  I honestly don't even understand the description of how you would like Windows to behave to even conclude if it's possible, but it probably isn't possible.

To clarify, I am referring to either a web email client or any other web UI that requires you to upload a file. Like Mac, on windows, a window pops out and ask you select an item to upload. But if the item is not in the directory of the window popped out, I want to drag the file into the window popout. In Mac, the popout window will change to show the directory the file is in, but in Window, it will move the item I dragged to that directory instead

Windows offers various controls for uploads in the various OS frameworks, but applications are also free to implement their own. You are asking for APPLICATION changes, more than OS changes. The good news is that an application is more likely to change significantly than an OS. But also, this question is really off topic here.

on Windows just copy the path to the folder or file and paste into the address bar on top or the "File name" field in the bottom of the Open dialog. It's far easier to get files that way compared to mac
